# A system for creating multilingual static websites

Tags: git, web, static, multilingual

I have a website I'm working on that I wish to add another few (properly translated) language options for, and I can't find as much readily accessible information as I thought I could on producing a multilingual website.

There's a nice amount of information on how to structure your URL schema (with .com/LANGUAGE being the nicest), but if you have http://www.example.com/en/, http://www.example.com/fr, and http://www.example.com/de — then for a static site, how do you avoid manually duplicating code just to drop-in each language's strings?

My site has about 8 webpages with on average 400 words of content on each page. It's not enough content to require a database for. However, the website is still in development and I don't want to wait until the 'end' (it's an informational tool) of its development cycle to create static versions for each language. I also don't want to swap out variables server-side because I am under the impression this will greatly diminish SEO scoring?

So, without much information of the topic available to me, I have devised a system/program that I would like some feedback of feasibility on - or if an alternative exists (?), before I begin.

- I am planning on creating **master** versions of each .html file (the
  only file that I actually edit for code changes) that contains a unique variable string for each instance of text
- Create /*language* directories for each language, copying over all files from the master
- Create a JSON file, structured appropriately to contain language strings for each variable
- Using a small C program, parse each language into the appropriate variables for each language's .html file

...As I am using .git, I would also copy over only changes that need to be made, by comparing strings against existing variables. — The way I could compare files I have not yet thought through — was thinking of storing the variable for each string as a .html tag so that it is always existent in the file.

Does anybody know if a tool like this exists, or if there is a much more compelling and SEO-compliant method of performing this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The web and web technology is so messy that, if you are only talking 3 or 4 languages, and only talking 8 or so pages ... I would personally at that scale just make them simple normal pages.

Comment: I found very [good explanations](https://developmentseed.org/blog/multilingual-jekyll-sites/) to do it with Jekyll but without an example :( (I pinged the author)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**edit**, 2020: now I'd go with [Hugo](https://gohugo.io/) (or equivalent). Hugo is easier to install, has many more features, is much faster, has more themes, has a bigger community.

A great solution, which appeared in december, 2015, is **Lektor**, a "static Content Management System".

- https://www.getlektor.com/
- https://github.com/lektor/lektor/

It's a static site builder with a built-in admin UI (to write posts and configure). Its system of "alternatives" is designed to localize and translate websites: https://www.getlektor.com/docs/content/alts/

```
pip install Lektor
lektor quickstart
```

It's a well established solution. Btw, it's by the creator of Flask.

Answer (score 2):

I found what may be exactly what we want: **Statirator**

plus solutions with **Jekyll**, thanks to [the answer of smit1678](https://github.com/smit1678/smit1678.github.com/issues/2#issuecomment-161008246).

## Statirator (or frozen-django)

- https://github.com/MeirKriheli/statirator
- https://statirator.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html#installation

which can be viewed as frozen-django (frozen-flask is a popular app).

It's on pypi:

```
pip install statirator # you may need to create a virtual env beforehand
```

then

```
statirator init mysite
```

it creates a skeleton project.

```
statirator create_post
```

it creates one rst file divided in as many sections as we configured languages

```
statirator generate
```

will generate the static site. It uses the Django configuration, so it's like frozen-django.

Unfortunately, it's not maintained and I couldn't make it work myself yet… (either I can't install it either `statirator init` doesn't exist).

Unfortunately again [/r/python](https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/3uejn5/statirator_multilingual_static_site_or/) didn't attract many interest at all.

## With Jekyll

I had found [good explanations](https://developmentseed.org/blog/multilingual-jekyll-sites/) to configure [Jekyll](http://jekyllrb.com/) as a multilingual site. Now came the examples: ([quoting Natan](https://github.com/smit1678/smit1678.github.com/issues/2#issuecomment-161008246))

- the [climatescope](https://github.com/climatescope/climatescope-2014) website. It uses a [translation file](https://github.com/climatescope/climatescope-2014/blob/master/_data/i18n_strings.yml) to manage most of the UI elements and then english and spanish pages are organized with _en or _es.
- we could also look at https://github.com/tristen/multilingual. This is based on previous versions of Jekyll. Jekyll's new [collections](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/collections/) feature changes the way it can be done.

Comment: Thanks for this; apologies for the delay in accepting. Choosing this one over your alternative later post as a Jekyll implementation is more open than a CMS. Thanks!

Comment: Hey, good surprise. Don't underlook Lektor, it's a static site builder in the vain of Jekyll and the better though of for a multilingual system IMO (and the one I picked).

Comment: Ah, okay thanks — since you've put the research in I trust your judgement; should I mark Lektor as the answer?

Comment: I think so, yes: Statirator doesn't work and is abandoned, the solution with Jekyll isn't well established and needs some work, whereas it's easy to start with Lektor, which is thought for that purpose and is maintained and popular.

Comment: Okay, thanks again for your valuable info!